Let Streambuilder in Row return nothing
I have a Row in my Flutter app with three buttons where one is optional.
The optional button will be activated through a FutureBuilder which checks if the service is activated.
A Futurebuilder must return something. So at first i just returned an empty SizedBox() but this will also get a placement in MainAxisAlignment in the Row.
Is there a way to just return nothing or even another way to build this?
example:
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
    ElevatedButton(),
    ElevatedButton(),
    FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: isServiceActive(),
      builder: (context, serviceActive) {
        if (serviceActive) {
          return ElevatedButton(),
        } 
// Else it should return nothing. 
// A empty SizedBox would take a place in MainAxisAlignment
        return ;
      },
    ),
  ],
);


You can use SizedBox.shrink() I think it has no effect on widget alignment.
(serivceActive) ? ElevatedButton(): SizedBox.shrink();

The above will work, but if you really need to put no thing if the service is not active. So you should have a predefined knowledge of the value of that Future variable.
class AnyName extends StatelessWidget{

bool serviceActive = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){

 initActiveService(); // now you know it before you build

 return Scaffold(

  body: Row(

    children : [

   ElevatedButton(),
   ElevatedButton(),
   if(activeService)
       ElevatedButton(),

   ]
    )

  );
}
void initActiveService()async{
 activeService = await getBooleanValue(); 
}
Future<bool> getBooleanValue()async{

return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1) , ()=>true);

}

 }

Or, you can even push the FutureBuilder higher than the row widget like other answers suggest: by @Md. Yeasin Sheikh and @Szymon Kowaliński
FutureBuilder(
future: isActive(),
builder:(context,data){

 return Row(
  children : [
 
 ElevatedButton(),
 ElevatedButton(),
  if(data)
     ElevatedButton(),

 ]
 )
}
)

Note: I just coded my idea directly on that answer, take as a pseudo code.
Hope it helps you.

Already tried this, sadly it still takes up a place in the row.

@EisGlockner , ok, see updates

@A-E StatelessWidget wont update the ui, if you like to use this approach, a ValueNotifier will help

@Md.YeasinSheikh, i hope he will catch the idea and apply it in its own desired way.

Thank you! I guess at first i will put the Futurebuilder over the Row, even tho the method returning the future is more beautiful imo.

@EisGlockner  u r wlcm.

I will suggest using FutureBuilder on top of Row widget and use a future variable on state class(for statefulWidget).
FutureBuilder<bool>(
  future: isServiceActiveFuture,
  builder: (context, serviceActive) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(),
        ElevatedButton(),
        if (serviceActive) ElevatedButton(),
      ],
    );
  },
);


I haven't tested the code but it should more or less look like this:
FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: isServiceActive(),
      builder: (context, serviceActive) {
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
    ElevatedButton(),
    ElevatedButton(),
    if (serviceActive)
    ElevatedButton(),
 
  ],
);
)

